# Save PostgreSQL shell output to file using Windows

Tags: windows, postgresql, shell, batch-file

I've created a pgsql script and saved it into a file.
This script is creating idexes. I need to run this script on several database.
I use PostgreSQL 9.3 on Windows 8.

I've created a batch file to call psql on every database and run the script. This works fine except in the shell I have a lot more messages than in my output file. Meaning when something goes wrong (i.e. a failed unique index) I see it in the shell but not in my output file. And because the shell is filled with messages I'm missing errors and warnings.

In my pgsql script I use

```
    SET client_min_messages to 'LOG';
    raise log 'Dropped index %', l_index_name;
```

My Windows batch file is

```
    @echo off
    set _psql="D:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin\psql.exe"
    set _server=localhost
    set _port=5432
    set _file=create_indexes.sql
    set _log=create_indexes.log

    FOR %%G IN (db1 db2 db3)  DO (
      %_psql% -d %%G -h %_server% -p %_port% -U postgres -w postgres <%_file% >>%_log%
      echo Done with %%G 
    )

    pause
```

I've been reading post about using >output.log, like

```
    create_indexes.bat >output.log
```

The file is created but has only a few irrelevant messages.

Any suggestion is more than welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to redirect not only stdout (stream 1) but also stderr (stream 2)

```
create_indexes.bat >output.log 2>&1
```

That is, send the output of the stderr to wherever the stream 1 is being sent